# djangobyexample book - jquery bookmarklet not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I'm working through Django By Example and in one chapter a jQuery bookmarklet is built within a Django app so that a user can easily save jpg images from a website into their user profile area within the Django app.

The tutorial does give exact instructions on what to do which I have followed and although I have managed to get the bookmarklet button to appear in my bookmarks bar in Chrome, nothing happens when I click it when browsing a webpage with jpg images.

This is my local Django dashboard where the bookmarklet button is added to the bookmarks bar and this part works fine

[image: dashboard image]

and this is how it must look like when clicked on the bookmarklet, this is the part where nothing happens for me when I clicked on bookmarklet.
(how to solve this?)

[image: expected image]

These are the relevant js files

https://github.com/davejonesbkk/bookmarks/blob/master/images/templates/bookmarklet_launcher.js

https://github.com/davejonesbkk/bookmarks/blob/master/images/static/js/bookmarklet.js

I believe the JavaScript launcher is unable to load the JavaScript files or the JS launcher itself is not getting loaded.

The JavaScript launcher is getting called through a Django template tag "include" inside the anchor tag.
this is the link:
https://github.com/davejonesbkk/bookmarks/blob/master/account/templates/account/dashboard.html

I tried debugging it through CTRL+SHIFT+I console where trouble showed that "include" tag not working properly.

Comment: you need to paste the relevant code in the question

Comment: If the include tag is not working, then please include the full error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `include` tag is split over two lines:

```
images from other websites → <a href="javascript:{% include
"bookmarklet_launcher.js" %}" class="button">Bookmark it</a><p>
```

Django does not support multiple line tags. Change it to:

```
images from other websites → <a href="javascript:{% include "bookmarklet_launcher.js" %}" class="button">Bookmark it</a><p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar error while going through the book.

The bookmark button is not functioning,when i debugged it through chrome debugger,i could able to see errors at js level.I have made two changes to resolve these errors.

1.Error message:  net::ERR_ABORTED

**Action step:**
   In the book its mentioned that to place **bookmarklet.js** in images application directory,but in **bookmarklet_launcher.js** the source is refered to below path

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=
```

So place **bookmarklet.js** in `/static/js/` directory inside images application(if folder structure not available create it).

2.Error message:  net::ERR_ABORTED

There is one more file that should be placed which is **bookmarklet.css** which is being refereed at below line in **bookmarklet.js**.

```
href: static_url + 'css/bookmarklet.css?r=' + Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999999999999)
```

**Action step:**

create a file **bookmarklet.css**  inside `/static/css/` directory and place the css code.Refer below link for css code:

[Git Hub link for css code reference](https://github.com/guinslym/django-by-example-book/blob/master/Django_By_Example_Code/Chapter%205/bookmarks/images/static/css/bookmarklet.css)

1.After the above steps,restart the development server.

2.Drag the bookmark it button to create a bookmark in browser.

3.Open any website that is HTTP(not https) and click on bookmark it(The one which is bookmarked in browser not bookmark it button).

[image]

4.The below pop up appears

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that template doesn't exist so try t do the following
**
1. make sure your include code in same line
2. make sure same name of the template exist on your project director /images/templates/file_name.js.
3. or go to setting and add your templates directory  to templates.
4. if it load but no images views don't forget that you only accept jpeg and jpg images only
** so you can try another sites like wikipedia **

Answer (score 0):

I was  able to solve this by making sure that the **url** from ngrok tunnel in the  **bookmarklet.js** and  **bookmarklet_luncher.js** starts with **https** not **http**

Instead of this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=` it should rather be

`https://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/bookmarklet.js?r=`

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of doing everything... googling, deleting code, and rewriting code...

Only had to hit Ctrl+C to stop server and re-run server .

Just take a break and come back to fix it :)

Mine works same as instructed in the book – no changes, no nothing.

Only restarted the server.